# .net core Startup.cs CreateScope or BuildServiceProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am just creating a new API and I have noticed from a couple of projects that I try to get **Config** files inside Startup.cs in different ways.
The first way is like this:

```
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var config = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IIdentityServerConfig>();
```

and the second way is like this:

```
var scope = services.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope();
var config = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Auth0Config>();
```

My question is, which one is right? Or does it not matter?

---

Here is an example:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors(m => m.AddPolicy(CorsName, o => o.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod()));
    services.AddLogging(Configuration, nameof(DataConfig));

    AddConfigs(services);
    AddSingletons(services);
    AddTransients(services);

    ConfigureStripe(services);

    AddDatabaseContexts(services);
    AddAuthentication(services);
    AddServices(services);

    services.AddMvc().AddFluentValidation(m => m.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<QuestionValidator>());
}
```

The `AddConfigs` method looks like this:

```
private void AddConfigs(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<Auth0Config>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(Auth0Config)));
    services.Configure<DataConfig>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(DataConfig)));
    services.Configure<EvaluatorConfig>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(EvaluatorConfig)));
    services.Configure<StripeConfig>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(StripeConfig)));
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
        options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
        options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
    });

    services.AddSingleton(m => m.GetRequiredService<IOptions<Auth0Config>>().Value);
    services.AddSingleton(m => m.GetRequiredService<IOptions<DataConfig>>().Value);
    services.AddSingleton(m => m.GetRequiredService<IOptions<EvaluatorConfig>>().Value);
    services.AddSingleton(m => m.GetRequiredService<IOptions<StripeConfig>>().Value);
}
```

And then you can see how I get a config for other services (for example the `AddAuthentication` method:

```
private static void AddAuthentication(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var scope = services.BuildServiceProvider().CreateScope();
    var config = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Auth0Config>();

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    }).AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
    {
        options.Authority = config.Authority;
        options.Audience = config.ApiAudience;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to add services to DI container. The common approach is to do that in `ConfigureServices` from `Startup` (also it is possible in Program.cs)

You don't need to call `services.BuildServiceProvider()` if you need an instance of `IIdentityServerConfig` in `ConfigureServices` method because you should already have it.

If you need the instance of `IIdentityServerConfig` in `Configure` method, then just pass it as a parameter like:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IIdentityServerConfig config)
{
}
```

or use `app`:

```
app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IIdentityServerConfig>();
```

so, the right way is not building service provider in Startup file

but if you really need this, I would prefer to use this one if you don't need a new scope (I think you don't need)

```
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var config = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IIdentityServerConfig>();
```

Comment: It's actually in ConfigureServices I need it. I register the config files and then some of the services I add use those configs

Comment: then you should have in `ConfigureServices`  something like: `var config = Configuration.GetSection("IIdentityServerConfig").Get<IIdentityServerConfig>(); services.AddSingleton(config);` then use `config` for other services.

Comment: but why do you need an instance of IIdentityServerConfig for other services, why not do it with DI in the constructor? Do you need a factory to build instance manually? It would be great to see your code from ConfigureServices

Comment: I will add it to the question

Comment: ok, thanks. I think it is not ok to do it so. Use feature approach to make things [hight cohesion](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/definition-high-cohesion#:~:text=High%20cohesion%20is%20a%20software,cohesion%20as%20high%20as%20possible.).  AddAuthentication should add all that need for auth, include configurations

Comment: Other than the two options I posted in the question, there is no other way to get the config file is there?